# CMake syntax to install custom generated files

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to make the following piece of `cmake` code handle the case where user calls `cpack` from the `cmd` window (instead of from within Visual Studio, clicking on 'PACKAGE' target). Currently it fails with:

```
c:\tmp>cpack.exe -G ZIP
CPack: Create package using ZIP
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Install project: GDCM
CMake Error at C:/tmp/gdcm-swig-x64/Wrapping/Csharp/cmake_install.cmake:60 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/tmp/gdcm-swig-x64/bin//gdcm-sharp.dll".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/tmp/gdcm-swig-x64/cmake_install.cmake:51 (include
)

CPack Error: Error when generating package: GDCM
```

Current code is inspired from [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-November/025372.html). And is like ([full code](https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/blob/master/Wrapping/Csharp/CMakeLists.txt#L121-L123)):

```
set(GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR2 ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}/\${BUILD_TYPE})
install(FILES ${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR2}/gdcm_csharp.dll
  DESTINATION ${GDCM_INSTALL_LIB_DIR} COMPONENT Runtime
)
```

where `gdcm_csharp.dll` is getting generated via a `add_custom_command` such as:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR}/gdcm_csharp.dll
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CSHARP_COMPILER} ARGS "/t:library" "/out:${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR}/gdcm_csharp.dll" "*.cs"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  DEPENDS "${swig_generated_file_fullname}" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/AssemblyInfo.cs
  COMMENT "csc *.cs"
)
```

Is there a way to fix the [`install(FILES)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files) to handle both cases (within Visual Studio, and outside) ?

Comment: In the `add_custom_command` you use `${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR}/gdcm_csharp.dll` as an output file. Why do not use the same expression when install the file?

Comment: @Tsyvarev https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-November/025371.html

Comment: Yes, I have read that mail, but it doesn't contain the answer to my question too. If `add_custom_command` **actually** produces the file, specified in `OUTPUT` option, then this file should be available for installation. If `COMMAND`, specified in `add_custom_command` actually produces **another file**, then `OUTPUT` specification is wrong, and it should be fixed independently from `install()`. So, which case is yours?

Answer (score 0):

To execute the PACKAGE target without explicitly running Visual Studio, you could  do the following:

```
cmake --build C:/tmp/gdcm-swig-x64/ --config Release --target PACKAGE
```